# Meaning of [[label]] in mathematica

Tags: plotting, code-review, notation

We want to plot data on a log scale, so we used the loop over data on a log scale. 
E.g. the code is below,

```
list= Array[r,{1,5}];k=1;
For[a=Log[10, 0.0018856]], aa<=Log[10, 0.23], aa= aa+0.02,
aaa=10^(aa);
min1= funmin1[aaa];
max1= funmax1[aaa];
test= ma[x/. min1[[2]], y/. min1[[2]]], aaa];
...
```

My question is why put [[2]] after min1 and max1, what does it mean? Will that change the result if we just used min1? 
Thank you.

Comment: `[[ ]]` is `Part` in Mathematica. So if something is a list and you want specific part, you use `[[ n ]]` where `n` is the part number. It is also called an  index.  So the code must be looking for specific part to use.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616

Comment: @Nasser, I got it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs, it is useful to me. Thank you.